# How to Convert XML Date format to Cocoa

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a Date format:
2009-08-10T16:03:03Z

that I want to convert to:
@"MMM dd, HH:mm a"

I retrieve the xml format in an NSString. I tried to use the NSDateformatter:
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, HH:mm a"];

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString *yourXMLDate = @"2009-08-10T16:03:03Z" 
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *inputDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:yourXMLDate];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, HH:mm a"];
NSString *outputDate = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me: 2012-06-29 16:58:11.868 tabbed-test[36214:11903] yourXMLDate: 2012-06-29T14:27:45Z
2012-06-29 16:58:11.870 tabbed-test[36214:11903] InputDate: (null)

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, d LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"]; // Thu, 18 Jun 2010 04:48:09 -0700
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.currentDate];

    [item setObject:date forKey:@"date"];

    [items addObject:[item copy]];
```

here edit the following code

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, d LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"]; // Thu, 18 Jun 2010 04:48:09 -0700
```

to your required Format.